# Friends met up at the bar

Tags: lateral-thinking

> During deer season, some friends met up at the bar. The first guy,
>   proud of what he accomplished during the week, says "I shot two 6
>   pointers and an 8 pointer." The second guy, not to be outdone, says
>   "Nice, but I shot a 12 pointer." The last guy, says "I shot a family
>   and their dog." None of his friends are shocked by what he said. Why?

Comment: they are all homicidal maniacs

Comment: The bar is the Villain Pub!

Comment: It's the Mos Eisley cantina! :)

Comment: @Rubio if you said that in [Mos Eisley](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/198) people might be a *little* shocked... but not much.

Comment: Because that last man had already been imprisoned for more than 10 years for accidental manslaughter, and had gone crazy in jail, leading to his repeating that same phrase in response to any question. "Hey Chad, what did you have for breakfast today?" "I shot a family and their dog."

Comment: Because that's what the first 2 guys paid him to do, since they had a running feud with their neighbor, whose dog always shat on their front walk.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

This is a fairly simple one I've heard before in a different guise...

They are not surprised because

> He is a photographer!